# Deleting a specific record from a row from a column in phpMyadmin SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-key

I have a database with a table that has a column called "adminID" and a 
duplicate entry in the admin_id column. The problem is that I didn't know that the column was not set to auto-increment, and as a result any edit of the user in the admin panel that this database serves creates a duplicate entry (a new user with the same ID)...now both have an id of "0". I cannot delete the user in the admin panel (i.e. - NOT the database itself, but the web admin portal) because it will grab the user id, which is "0" and delete both of the users, and as a result I will not be able to log into the system admin panel.

I would like to 1st remove one of the duplicate entries and then I would like to set the column to be a unique key and have it auto increment. However, I am not sure of the SQL statement to delete a record from a column. Should I delete both users and then set the column to be unique key, and THEN re-create the user for admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

disregard...I ran: DELETE FROM `admin_user_table` WHERE `first_name`="Scott";

It did what I was needing